# Import chrome.scripting.ExecutionWorld type

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension

The Chrome type declaration `@types/chrome` declares `ExecutionWorld` as per below:

```
declare namespace chrome.scripting {

    /* The CSS style origin for a style change. */
    export type StyleOrigin = 'AUTHOR' | 'USER';

    /* The JavaScript world for a script to execute within. */
    export type ExecutionWorld = 'ISOLATED' | 'MAIN';
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to import and use this in my code though?

```
const ew = chrome.scripting.ExecutionWorld.MAIN;
```

Gives the error `Property 'ExecutionWorld' does not exist on type 'typeof scripting'.ts(2339)`

```
import { type ExecutionWorld } from "chrome.scripting";
```

Gives the error `Property 'Cannot find module 'chrome.scripting' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

Comment: There's no need to import it in order to use it because `chrome` is a global symbol, but you may want to install the **official** [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types) to suppress the linter warning and improve auto-complete in IDE. Note that you should add `scripting` to `permissions` in manifest.json to enable the API.